# replacing spaces and brackets in a string + sed + is there a better way than this?

Tags: bash, sed

trying to replace the sapces and underscores in `this is just a (test)`

I do the following:

```
echo "this is just a (test)"  | sed -e 's/ /_/g' | sed -e 's/(//g' | sed -e 's/)//g'
```

And this gives me:

```
this_is_just_a_test
```

Is there a better way? shorter way of writing it in sed?

Comment: You can at least combine the `-e` statements in one single `sed` call:  `sed -e 's/ /_/g' -e 's/(//g' -e 's/)//g'` or shorter: `sed -e 's/ /_/g' -e 's/[()]//g'`.  You can replace characters by `tr` instead.  `tr` can also be used (in a second call) to strip specific characters.  But all in all this does not help very much, so I'd stick with the (single) `sed` call.

Comment: You can chain multiple `sed` commands together using a `;`. So perhaps `sed 's/ /_/g; s/[()]//g'` is more to the point.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same thing using [tr](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tr):

```
echo "this is just a (test)" | tr \  _ | tr -d \(\)
```

The first tr replaces spaces with underscores and the second one deletes all parenthesis.